# Serializer for inherited model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I have following models declared:

```py
class Parent(models.Model):
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Child(Parent)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
```

and serializer:

```py
class ChildSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Child
        fields = ('active', 'name')
```

At glance everything seems to be ok, it's correctly generated in the browsable api. Neverthless when I want to update both fields only 'active' is updated.

When I do put in return I receive correct resonse:

```
{
  "active": true,
  "name": "foo"
}
```

But the name field is not updated at all. I went further and tried to implemented custom update method in the serializer:

```py
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    print(str(type(instance)))
    return instance
```

After that in a put response I'm receiving only active field ?:

```
{
  "active": true,
}
```

And on console even more astonishing:

```
rest_1  | <class 'applic.models.Person'>
```

I'm completely lost :) Why on earth serializer treats explicitly provided Child model as a Person ?  How to force ChildSerializer to work on Child model ?

Thank you in advance
Piotr

Comment: your models are not related what is the relationship is it 1 to 1, 1 to many ..etc ?

Comment: hi, when you derive one model from another  their relationship is 1 to 1 (at least it looks like this in db), except this, there is no other relationship

Comment: Ok, the problem is with update but creation is working fine ?

Comment: Hi, yes for creation is working fine

Comment: Can you add your views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `models.py` as below,

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Child(Parent):
    parent = models.OneToOneField(Parent)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
```

and try `ModelViewSet` in `views.py` as below,

```
class YourViewClass(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ChildSerializer
    queryset = Child.objects.all()
```

Assuming your api end-point is `/api/vi/sample/`, then 
to `add` instance, use `POST` method on `/api/vi/sample/`
payload will be as below

```
{
    "active": true,
    "name": "name_choice"
}
```

to `edit` instance, `PUT` or `PATCH` on `/api/vi/sample/instance_id` where `instance_id` is an integer representing the `primary key` of the `Child` instance (example :`/api/vi/sample/1` ). Updated payload as below,

```
{
    "active": false,
    "name": "name_choice_new_change"
}
```

If you'd like to see the `instance_id`, update your `serializer` as follows,

```
class ChildSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Child
        fields = ('id', 'active', 'name')
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for the solution. Nevertheless I'm still super  curious why is that (because above trick it's more workaround IMHO). For me it looks like a bug, but I'm not sure. Can anyone explain it to me ?

Comment: `Parent` and `Child` models are dependent and they must be in `OneToOne Relationship` as you mentioned in the question. In Django, this is how it implemented. This is the official doc for `one to one` relationship, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/

Comment: In short, this is how it should be ;)